# Get Datas of the python list (from json)

Tags: python, json

I have list such

```
print data[0]
{u'CityId': 3969, u'DistrictCode': 599, u'Id': 0, u'AreaWideCode': 18439, u'DistrictName': u'Adalar'}
```

But i could not figured out to get the items from the list. I would expect as

```
print data[0][1]
3969
```

But could not get it.

*PS: the overall code;*

```
import requests
import json

payload = {'cityId':3969, 'cmd':'districts'}
url = "https://www.garantimortgage.com/apps/Socket/Webservice.ashx"
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)


data = json.loads(r.text) #json to python data structure conversion
print data[0]
```

Comment: You want the first element's `CityId` only?

Comment: That's **not a list**, it's a dictionary. Try reading https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a dictionary. To get value, you have to use key:

```
>>> data[0]['CityId']
3969
```